# can someone explain why an inplace function doesn't work on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i am attempting to change the values within one of the series in a dataframe:

```
df_dupes.loc[:,'primary_numbers'].map( lambda x: list(x).sort() )
```

when i call `df_dupes['primary_numbers']` it seems that the lists is not sorted. in fact, the lists are still tuples as before this mapping is done

and when i print, i get None for all the values in the data series.

now, if i try `df_dupes.loc[:,'primary_numbers'].map( lambda x: sorted(list(x))) )`

it will print what i want, but it won't change the data series because it's not an in place function.

i keep getting SettingWithCopyWarning so i tried it this way instead and it doesn't work...wondering why

edit:  `[x for x in df_dupes.loc[:,'overlay_npas']].sort()` doesn't work either

Comment: Assign results back to the column `df_dupes['primary_numbers'] = df_dupes['primary_numbers'].map(sorted)`

Comment: @Psidom is there a way to change them to lists first, since they are tuples?  like ```df_dupes['primary_npas'] = df_dupes['primary_npas'].map( sorted(list) )```

Comment: You might have `df_dupes` as a subset of another data frame. You can copy the dataframe with `.copy()` to avoid the. error.

Comment: `sorted` works on `tuple` too. I think there's no need to convert tuples to list.

Comment: @Psidom yes i believe it is a subset

Comment: What does the 'primary_numbers' dataset look like?  Is each value just an integer?  And also, your example is not an in place function.

Comment: @elPastor i thought .sort() sorts a list in place

Comment: @Psidom curious in general would there be a way to apply both methods/functions?

Comment: `.sort` returns `None`, hence your function returns `None`, there's no reason why you couldn't use an in-place sort and return the list instead of `None`

Comment: Note, `sorted` takes an arbitrary iterable and returns a sorted list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i might be getting confused here... i thought ```.sort``` is an inplace method for lists.  how would i do an in place sort in the context of a data series? thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  if i have something like this:  ```print (  df_dupes.loc[:,'primary_numbers'].map(lambda x: list(x).sort()) )```  it will return ```None``` as you say, and now i understand why.  but shouldn't it update the values in that data Series??

Comment: @avnav99 no. `list(x).sort()` creates a list, sorts it, throws it away (since you don't reference it anywhere). `tuple` objects are *immutable anyways*. If you did that and they were lists instead, they would be modified (well, not if you did `list(x).sort()` but just `x.sort()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok i tested it out and i see what you mean if the elements inside were lists it does appear that ```df_dupes['overlay_npas'].map(lambda x: x.sort())``` would sort them in place which makes sense, thank you